# is there an R function to remove an observation when 2 variables are the same?

Tags: r

[image]

I am having tough time with this. I wanted to remove the rows that has the same from and to station names. How can I do that in R? Please help.

Comment: `subset(df, to!=from)`

Comment: or more basic: `df[df$from != df$to, ]`

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: Thanks to all of you for helping. Cheers!

Comment: Greetings! Typically it is recommended to provide a minimally reproducible dataset with your question. One way of achieving this is by using the `dput` command. You can check out how to do this at this video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg